How to perform a left shift of discrete signals via convolution operation in python?
A left shift of t0 in a signal can be obtained by convolving it with δ(t+t0). I want to obtain this in python using discrete signals by only using the np.convolve operator in mode='full'. Note that I can't use np.roll or assignment from an index like [shift:]. It has to be obtained purely by convolution. Here's an example:
signal = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
shift = 3
filter = ??
shifted_signal = np.convolve(signal, filter, mode='full')
print(shifted_signal)

[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, ...

The number of zeros at the right side, or to say the length of shifted_signal is not important. But I want the signal to start from the correct position. What should the filter be such that I get the desired output? I need it this way because I am trying to obtain the left shift from an FFT analysis. A left shift of t0 in the time domain corresponds to a multiplication of ei2πft0 in the frequency domain. I can obtain t0 by comparing the shifted signal with the original in the frequency domain. But to check if my algorithm works, I just can't think of a filter that performs a left shift in the time domain.
I tried filter = [0, 0, 0, 1] and filter = [1, 0, 0, 0] but they adds zeros to the left and right of the signal. The signal itself doesn't start from the desired index. I have no idea what other filter I can use to obtain the desired result.

who requires you to use the full mode and why do they require this of you?

Why does it have to be obtained by convolution? Surely it is much easier to read the appropriate values from the array with suitable protection for reading off the end. Convolving with a shifted delta is an expensive operation to use for this trivial action.

must be a class assignment... in which case I don't quite see the point in requiring full. that just adds another step of consideration for how the signal will shift. starting with same would be a good idea to understand how the kernel affects the signal

OK guys, here's what I'm doing. I'm performing 1D signal deconvolution in the frequency domain. A measured signal is the convolution of an original signal with a kernel, followed by a left time shift of 't0'. An inverse FFT of the division of the kernel FFT from the measured signal FFT gives the original signal but right-shifted in time. By multiplying the kernel by e^(i2pi*f *t0) to account for the left shift of 't0', I get my original signal. But I wonder, i.e., if python can model a left shift in the time domain at all? Hence, my question. I think NOT since python has no negative indices.

The use case I mentioned in the question is a valid application of obtaining 't0' when not known a priori. By comparing the original and left shifted signals in the frequency domain, I can evaluate the factor e^(i* 2 * pi * f * t0) and from it I can obtain my t0.

You can't shift signal left using standard convolution (without cutting the signal as mode 'same' does). There is no filter kernel that could accomplish that. If you could do that you could also travel back in time or foresee future.
Convolution can represent Linear System that has an input and some changed delayed (or not, but definitely not hastened) output. If it could "hasten" signals it would mean it could read future - give some information on the output about signal that hasn't yet entered input.
EDIT: addressing comment
However, we are in digital domain, and can interpret results of the discrete convolution a bit arbitrarily. We can assume any time domain we want for the convolution kernel.
We can say that kernel (e.g. [1, 0, 0]) has time domain of [-1, 0, 1]. For simplicity signal has time domain [0, 1, 2..].
This way result of the convolution will have time domain shifted, to the beginning of kernel: [-1, 0, 1, 2..]. And we accomplished shifting signal left.
We could use any time domain we wanted for the kernel and have different result, but the one that is symmetrical around 0 seems common sense.

Well, that was a weird answer but I still appreciate it. Although I think that your conclusion is true, i.e., left shift may not be possible in python with np.convolve, I don't think your reasoning is sound. You see a left shift may not be possible PHYSICALLY but it is possible MATHEMATICALLY, i.e., by convolution with a δ(t+t0). Try it out and see for yourself.

@PratikDash take a look at the edit, it addresses your mathematical case

Thanks for the edit. I too came to the same conclusion and the exact same remedy. One can always account for the 'time' digitally with a separate array. One point about your comment on the time domain. It doesn't need to be symmetric about zero. It only needs to cover those time instants where the signal and the kernel are defined. Do check my answer and let me know what you think. Will appreciate any suggestions for improvement.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78819376/how-to-perform-a-left-shift-of-discrete-signals-via-convolution-operation-in-pyt/78828751#78828751

@PratikDash Yes, as I wrote, we can assume any time domain for convolution kernel :) That being said, it is common to use such symmetric around zero approach.

I got your desired result by switching the mode to same. Here is the code
import numpy as np
signal = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
shift = 3
filter = [1]
for i in filter:
    if len(filter) < 2 * shift + 1:
        filter.append(0)
    else:
        break
shifted_signal = np.convolve(signal, filter, mode='same')
print(shifted_signal)

Output is
[4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0]

This could probably be improved by using list comprehension

I specifically mentioned to only use mode='full'. Problem with mode='same' is that it implicitly performs a left time shift which leaves its footprint in the ffts. Since fourier transform of the convolution of two functions is the product of their fourier transforms, check this for your case and you will find that real and imaginary parts of fft of shifted_signal and product of the ffts of signal and filter will not match. You have to first make both signal and filter have the same frequency axis. interpolation may be necessary). Just tried this and that's indeed the case. They don't match.

full pads. same doesn't shift, unless your kernel effects that.

mode='full' doesn't pad. It does the convolution operation exactly as per its definition. The extra zeros are not padding. Rather mode='same' trims the output obtained from mode='full' to have the same length of its first input after first centering it. So you see, there is a time shift involved in mode='same' which is encoded in its FFT. You can check it for a simple case of, say, a convolution with a Gaussian kernel.

After realizing that it may not be possible to perform a left shift via convolution with a Dirac delta function using only np.convolve(, mode='full') since there is no concept of negative indices in arrays in python, I manually defined a time axis to perform discrete convolution based on its elements rather than the indices of arrays. The execution is crude and runs very slowly for large arrays but it serves as a proof-of-concept. The code below shows an example.
Special mention to @dankal444 who also had the same suggestion in the edit to his answer.
# performing a left shift via convolution in python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# custom define a convolution function
def convolve(signal, kernel, time):
    # initialize a convolution array
    conv = np.zeros_like(time)
    
    # flip the kernel about time=0
    flipped_kernel = np.flip(kernel)
    inverted_time = np.flip(time)*-1
    
    # now loop through time
    for i, t in enumerate(time):
        # shift the flipped kernel
        shifted_inverted_time = inverted_time + t
        
        # get the times when the flipped kernel overlaps with the signal
        time_overlap_indices = np.where((time >= shifted_inverted_time.min()) & (time <= shifted_inverted_time.max()))[0]
        sit_overlap_indices = np.where((shifted_inverted_time >= time.min()) & (shifted_inverted_time <= time.max()))[0]
        
        # make sure that both have the same times
        if len(time_overlap_indices) > len(sit_overlap_indices):
        
            if time[time_overlap_indices[0]] != shifted_inverted_time[sit_overlap_indices[0]] or \
                    time[time_overlap_indices[-1]] != shifted_inverted_time[sit_overlap_indices[-1]]:
        
                time_overlap_indices = time_overlap_indices[1:] if (time[time_overlap_indices[0]] !=
                                                                    shifted_inverted_time[sit_overlap_indices[0]]) \
                                                                else time_overlap_indices[:-1]
        elif len(time_overlap_indices) < len(sit_overlap_indices):
        
            if shifted_inverted_time[sit_overlap_indices[0]] != time[time_overlap_indices[0]] or \
               shifted_inverted_time[sit_overlap_indices[-1]] != time[time_overlap_indices[-1]]:
        
                sit_overlap_indices = sit_overlap_indices[1:] if (shifted_inverted_time[sit_overlap_indices[0]] !=
                                                                  time[time_overlap_indices[0]]) \
                                                                else sit_overlap_indices[:-1]

        # get the convolution at index 'i'
        conv[i] = np.sum(signal[time_overlap_indices] * flipped_kernel[sit_overlap_indices])

    return conv

# Example 1D signal
time = np.linspace(-10, 8, 10000)
signal = np.exp(-(time-5)**2)

# define a left shift Dirac delta function
shift = -9 # in μs
leftShift = np.zeros_like(time)
leftShift[np.where(time >= shift)[0][0]] = 1

# get the convolved signal
convolved_signal = convolve(signal, leftShift, time)

# plot the signal, kernel and the convolved signal
plt.figure()
# plot the signals in the time domain
plt.plot(time, signal, label='signal', color='C0')
plt.axvline(time[np.argmax(signal)], color='C0', linestyle='--',
            label='signal peak at t = {} μs'.format(np.round(time[np.argmax(signal)], 2)))

plt.axvline(x=shift, ymin=0, ymax=1, color='C2', linestyle='--', 
            label='left shift of {} μs'.format(np.round(shift, 2)))

plt.plot(time, convolved_signal, label='convolved signal', color='C1')

plt.axvline(time[np.argmax(convolved_signal)], color='C1', linestyle='--',
            label='convolved signal \npeak at t = {} μs'.format(np.round(time[np.argmax(convolved_signal)], 2)))

# append new ticks to the current ticks
plt.xticks(np.append(plt.gca().get_xticks(), np.round([shift, time[np.argmax(signal)], time[np.argmax(convolved_signal)]], 2)))
plt.xlabel('Time (in μs)'), plt.ylabel('Amplitude'), plt.grid(), plt.legend()
plt.title('Left shift of {} μs'.format(shift))



your first sentence already contradicts reality. Python has no issues at all with negative indices in arrays. nor does numpy. they take that just fine.

OK, I agree that the term 'negative indices' might have caused confusion. Let me clarify what I mean. I don't mean the functionality of python where an index of -1 refers to the last element and -2 refers to the second last element and so on. I mean a unique index holding a different value. Like an element at index -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, and so on. This is in the context of discrete convolution. See #dankal444's edit to his answer for more clarity.
I don't know to call it exactly. But to anyone that looks at my code, it will be clear what I mean.

Improvements: 1) time -> time_domain  2) use np.convolve(a, v, mode='full') instead of custom function 3) all you need to do then is adjust time domain of the result of the convolution (just add start of time domain of the filter kernel signal)
